# Functional version of operators in Java?

Tags: java, java-8

I'm looking for an equivalent of python's [Operator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) package for python. This would allow to use operators as functions in reduce (for example) without having to create a new lambda function

Comment: There's `Integer::sum`, but I don't think the rest come pre-packaged.

Comment: java is far away from python... it would be better if you post what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far...

Comment: I just want to replace Stream.reduce((x, y) -> x || y) by Stream.reduce(Operators::or) if possible, because it looks cleaner and avoid defining a new lambda

Comment: @Phrodo_00 you're looking for `Boolean::logicalOr`.  But frankly it's not likely to actually be any more efficient in reality than `(x, y) -> x || y`.

Comment: I like the `Boolean::logicalOr`. To me it seems a bit more readable. And the method was most certainly introduced with such an application in mind (for 99.99 % of uses, efficiency shouldn’t be driving the choice).

Comment: That's exactly what `Boolean::logicalOr` was designed for, but I'm not sure what your aversion to defining a "new" lambda is -- the two will compile to essentially the same bytecode.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Kind of off-topic, but why was it called `Boolean::logicalOr` instead of simply `Boolean::or`? And why aren't there equivalent bit operations on `Integer` or `Long`?

Comment: @shmosel Don't over-think it...

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try Scala, you can bring some of your Java code into a Scala application. Then you can do something like you requested:

```
// Simulate a small stream
val stream = true #:: false #:: true #:: Stream.empty

// With lambda
val result1 = stream.reduce(_ || _)
println("Result 1 = " + result1)

// Define function 
val OpOR = (x: Boolean, y: Boolean) => {x || y}

// Pass function as argument to perform OR operation
val result2 = stream.reduce(OpOR)
println("Result 2 = " + result2)
```

In both cases output of each Result will be `true`.

See:

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-walk-scala-collections-reduceleft-foldright-cookbook

http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-stream-class-lazy-list-scala-cookbook

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in Java 8, using info from comments:

```
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;

public class Main {
    void reduceDemo() {
        Stream<Boolean> booleanStream = Stream.of(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE);

        Optional<Boolean> reduced = booleanStream.reduce(Boolean::logicalOr);

        System.out.println("reduced:  " + reduced.get());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        m.reduceDemo();
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
reduced:  true
```